# Locate cursor on the screen

Tags: cursor

I have a big monitor and sometimes it can be difficult to locate the small blinking underscore that is the cursor.

Is there a way to temporarily make the cursor more prominent and visible?

Note, I am using just plain virtual consoles, so there is no windowing system or GUI or anything like that.

Comment: GUI? Then see `:h 'guicursor'`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `cursorcolumn` and/or the `cursorline` to highlight the line and/or column the cursor is on:

```
:set cursorcolumn cursorline
```

By adding a `!` to the end of the option you can toggle the value, which is useful especially if you want to map this to a key, for example:

```
:nnoremap <F2>      :set cursorcolumn! cursorline!<CR>
:inoremap <F2> <C-o>:set cursorcolumn! cursorline!<CR>
```

You can configure the appearance with the `CursorColumn` and `CursorLine` highlight groups.

Answer (score 2):

Damian Conway wrote some functions to help him find his cursor when jumping around with `n`. I'm sure they could be adapted for your use case (i.e., instead of the right-hand side being `n:call ...`, just do the `call`).

```
" This rewires n and N to do the highlighing...
nnoremap <silent> n   n:call HLNext(0.4)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N   N:call HLNext(0.4)<cr>

" EITHER blink the line containing the match...
function! HLNext (blinktime)
    set invcursorline
    redraw
    exec 'sleep ' . float2nr(a:blinktime * 1000) . 'm'
    set invcursorline
    redraw
endfunction

" OR ELSE ring the match in red...
function! HLNext (blinktime)
    highlight RedOnRed ctermfg=red ctermbg=red
    let [bufnum, lnum, col, off] = getpos('.')
    let matchlen = strlen(matchstr(strpart(getline('.'),col-1),@/))
    echo matchlen
    let ring_pat = (lnum > 1 ? '\%'.(lnum-1).'l\%>'.max([col-4,1]) .'v\%<'.(col+matchlen+3).'v.\|' : '')
            \ . '\%'.lnum.'l\%>'.max([col-4,1]) .'v\%<'.col.'v.'
            \ . '\|'
            \ . '\%'.lnum.'l\%>'.max([col+matchlen-1,1]) .'v\%<'.(col+matchlen+3).'v.'
            \ . '\|'
            \ . '\%'.(lnum+1).'l\%>'.max([col-4,1]) .'v\%<'.(col+matchlen+3).'v.'
    let ring = matchadd('RedOnRed', ring_pat, 101)
    redraw
    exec 'sleep ' . float2nr(a:blinktime * 1000) . 'm'
    call matchdelete(ring)
    redraw
endfunction

" OR ELSE briefly hide everything except the match...
function! HLNext (blinktime)
    highlight BlackOnBlack ctermfg=black ctermbg=black
    let [bufnum, lnum, col, off] = getpos('.')
    let matchlen = strlen(matchstr(strpart(getline('.'),col-1),@/))
    let hide_pat = '\%<'.lnum.'l.'
            \ . '\|'
            \ . '\%'.lnum.'l\%<'.col.'v.'
            \ . '\|'
            \ . '\%'.lnum.'l\%>'.(col+matchlen-1).'v.'
            \ . '\|'
            \ . '\%>'.lnum.'l.'
    let ring = matchadd('BlackOnBlack', hide_pat, 101)
    redraw
    exec 'sleep ' . float2nr(a:blinktime * 1000) . 'm'
    call matchdelete(ring)
    redraw
endfunction

" OR ELSE just highlight the match in red...
function! HLNext (blinktime)
    let [bufnum, lnum, col, off] = getpos('.')
    let matchlen = strlen(matchstr(strpart(getline('.'),col-1),@/))
    let target_pat = '\c\%#\%('.@/.'\)'
    let ring = matchadd('WhiteOnRed', target_pat, 101)
    redraw
    exec 'sleep ' . float2nr(a:blinktime * 1000) . 'm'
    call matchdelete(ring)
    redraw
endfunction
```

- Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHm36-na4-4
- Code: https://is.gd/IBV2013

Comment: How are you finding out the cause of the change? Everyone deserves the benefit of the doubt. I always politely remind people of the way things work because there may be any number of reasons why they aren't aware. But in those rare cases where someone already knows and vigorously doesn't give a crap, appeasement is a nothing strategy. I guess you and whoever deleted my comment don't believe there are any bad guys in the world. What color, may I ask, is the sky there in your world?

Comment: @BLayer Re: benefit of the doubt... I didn't delete your comment (though on second read that may not be what you indented with that sentence). Certainly there are bad people. I don't know what changed, just that OP used to adhere to SE norms and doesn't now. And I don't have any way to force OP to tell me (nor have I politely asked). I guess I'm having a hard time following why you're responding so harshly to my answer (I understand your reaction to OP, generally). I'm not appeasing OP—I'm aiding the multitudes who might wonder something similar and stumble here. Happy to [chat] sometime...

Comment: P.S. I would also point out that one of the most respected members of our little community posted an answer, and *after* I did. Surely Martin felt there was value in answering too?

Comment: No I said "you and whoever deleted" the comment. I don't think  it's you. I don't think my comment is _that_ harsh. If you do then that's not good. Anyways, I might write something in Meta on all this. Been bothering me for a while. 'Preciate the offer of a chat...maybe later.

Comment: @BLayer no, your reaction to the OP (and subsequent comment) felt moderate and "forewarning" more than harsh, all things considered. Perhaps a bit of lingering frustration, but fairly, and nothing worth getting upset about. If I were to speculate, I'd say it didn't fit into SE's "comment model" (clarification and all that). I look forward to seeing what you write, and thanks for staying engaged... I know it can be difficult when people are (knowingly or unknowingly) obnoxious

Comment: I flagged the comment on the question as it's off-topic @BLayer; nothing more or less. If you want to have a discussion about what to do with people who don't accept questions then meta is a better place for that, IMHO. Personally, I think that the entire "accept" feature is somewhere between useless and actively harmful, so I couldn't care less if people accept my answer or not (votes are much more useful).

Comment: @MartinTournoij Really? When looking for answers that green checkbox is pretty useful to me. (BTW I'm not sure if the person in question votes either unless they get theirs first.) Anyways, yeah, if I feel like expending the required energy I'll put any further thoughts on Meta.

Comment: @BLayer The biggest issue I have is that the asker of the question is by definition unqualified to choose the "best" answer, since they're the ones asking a question. And in many cases there are multiple good answers without a clear "best" one, for example in this case my solution is not "better" or "worse" than Ben's (is it Ben? "D. Ben" is confusing), just different. Why should mine be accepted just because the OP likes it more? I also dislike the "pin on top" (which is a bit less of an issue on Vim, but on SO some pretty old/bad answers are pinned on top).

Comment: @MartinTournoij Ben works.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Yeah, if the accept "quality" here is better than most SE sites I concede that that's probably skewing me positive since I'm here a highly disproportionate amount of time (had a brief run on U&L but that was a while ago). Certainly the second issue you mention doesn't come up as much here since there's almost never more than an answer or two to choose from.

Comment: What about "DBK"? :D

Comment: I think you're only allowed to do that if you're president @BLayer: FDR, JFK, LBJ. I think he still has some way to go, but DBK wouldn't be the worst addition to that list I can think of 